# What is the PK and FK i should assign to my table?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key, entity-relationship, erd

A company provides transport services to high-ranked staffs.
There are 3 tables: DRIVERS, VEHICLES, STAFFS.

DRIVERS
- license number [PK]
- name
- language spoken
- ... (and so on..)

VEHICLES
- vehicle ID [PK]
- registration number
- model
- colour
- ... and so on...

STAFFS
- staff ID [PK]
- name
- position name
- ... and so on....

I want to create a new table called ORGANIZE
whereby, it will assign a driver and a vehicle to match the needs of the staff. 
what will be the PK and FKs?

Comment: Thank you Chase :) it ain't homework. It's a major project!

Comment: look at the answer I'm compiling on your other project. I do however recommend not taking on projects of this nature without full knowledge of database design. You could be in for some serious issues.

Comment: You don't appear to be storing the needs of the staff. Start with that.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a more exhaustive answer over at your other question.
[normalization of database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946085/normalization-of-database)

If you need to match a driver and a vehicle to a staff member, then you can do a three column composite pk with fk associations with the three other tables. You'll need to wire up your own logic to actually do the organization... this would not be done in the database, the db should just retain the results of the organization.