# normalization of database

Tags: database, dependencies, primary-key, normalization, partial

I would like to ask about a question relating to normalization.

I have 2 PKs, VIN and Reg_no.
VIN is the Vehicle ID Number and Registration number is the car plate number.
I have an attribute called current odometer. 
Does it have a partial dependency or a full dependency on the 2 PKs?

Answer (score 1):

> I have 2 PKs, VIN and Reg_no. VIN is the Vehicle ID Number and
>   Registration number is the car plate number.

You have two candidate keys. VIN is unique; the plate number is also *probably* unique. (But it depends on your application.)

Any key can consist of multiple columns, but you don't have one multi-column key, you have either one key (VIN) or two separate keys (VIN and plate). And there's nothing wrong with that.

> I have an attribute called current odometer. Does it have a partial
>   dependency or a full dependency on the 2 PKs?

Regardless of whether you have only one key or two in this table, each key has only one column. Since each possible key has only one column, it's impossible to have a partial key dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You probably only need ONE PK. Use the VIN since it's absolutely unique. Registration Number could be "re-used" across states/provinces.

Your "Composite Primary Keys" will be on your join tables where needed.

**VEHICLE_TABLE**

```
VIN                  nvarchar(50) [pk]
RegistrationNumber   nvarchar(50)
NumberOfPassengers   int
Make                 nvarchar(20)
Model                nvarchar(20)
Color                nvarchar (20)
Features             nvarchar(MAX)
```

**DRIVER_TABLE**

```
DriverID             int [pk]
Name                 nvarchar(20)
Address              nvarchar(50)
OtherCrap            nvarchar(MAX)
```

**POSITION_TABLE**

```
PositionID           int [pk]
Position             nvarchar(50)
```

**MAINTENANCE_TABLE**

```
MaintenanceID        int [pk]
VIN                  nvarchar(50) [fk - VEHICLE_TABLE.VIN]
Odometer             decimal(9,2)
MaintenanceDate      DateTime
```

**STAFF_TABLE**

```
StaffID              int [pk]
Name                 nvarchar(20)
PositionID           int [fk - POSITION_TABLE.PositionID]
```

**VEHICLE_JOIN_DRIVER_TABLE**

```
VIN                  nvarchar(50) [cpk fk - VEHICLE_TABLE.VIN]
DriverID             int [cpk fk - DRIVER_TABLE.DriverID]
```

**VEHICLE_JOIN_STAFF_TABLE**

```
VIN                  nvarchar(50) [cpk fk - VEHICLE_TABLE.VIN]
DriverID             int [cpk fk - DRIVER_TABLE.DriverID]
StaffID              int [cpk fk - STAFF_TABLE.StaffID]
```

This answer also attempts to "somewhat" answer your other question.
[What is the PK and FK i should assign to my table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601416/what-is-the-pk-and-fk-i-should-assign-to-my-table)